# Setting up relationships with mongoDB, node and angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

I am new to node, coming from Ruby on Rails, and I am attempting to set up a database like so:
*User has many Groups and Posts. Each group belongs to a user. Each post belongs to a user and one or more groups.*

To do this, I think it would be best to use [embedded sub-documents](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-one-relationships-between-documents/#data-modeling-example-one-to-one) instead of [references](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#data-modeling-publisher-and-books).

I understand the overall concept for how this should work, however, I am having a difficult time putting the pieces together. I am curious how I should set the database up, write the api, and then set up the controller. I have listed out what I have so far. Anything to point me in the right direction will be very helpful.

Thank you

**User Data Model**

```
    // app/models/user.js
// load the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var Post     = require('./post');
var Group    = require('./groups');

// define the schema for our user model
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
        username     : String,  
        group        : {
            name: String, 
            created      : {type:Date, default: Date.now},
                 post: { url: String, 
                         highlighted: String, 
                         comment: String, 
                         image: String, 
                         group: String, 
                         timeStamp: String, 
                         description: String, 
                         title: String,
                         created: {type:Date, default: Date.now} 
                    } 
        },
        created: {type:Date, default: Date.now} 

    }

});

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**API**

```
...
    router.route('/users')
            .post(function(req, res) {
                var user = new User();

                user.local.name     = req.body.name;
                user.local.email    = req.body.email;
                user.local.password = req.body.password;
                user.local.posts    = req.body.post;
                user.local.groups    = req.body.group;

                user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) 
                       res.send(err);

                    res.json({ message: 'user created!' });
                });
            }) 
            .get(function(req, res) {
                User.find(function(err, users) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.json(users);
                });
            });
        router.route('/users/:user_id')

            // get the post with that id (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api/users/:user_id)
            .get(function(req, res) {
                User.findById(req.params.user_id, function(err, user) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);
                    res.json(user);
                });
            })

            // update the user with this id (accessed at PUT http://localhost:8080/api/users/:user_id)
            .put(function(req, res) {

                // use our user model to find the user we want
                User.findById(req.params.user_id, function(err, user) {

                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    user.name           = req.body.name;
                    user.local.email    = req.body.email;
                    user.local.password = req.body.password;
                    user.local.posts    = req.body.post;
                    user.local.groups    = req.body.group;

                    // save the user
                    user.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            res.send(err);

                        res.json({ message: 'user updated!' });
                    });

                });
            })

            // delete the user with this id (accessed at DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/users/:user_id)
            .delete(function(req, res) {
                User.remove({
                    _id: req.params.user_id
                }, function(err, user) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
                });
            });
...
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.addUser = function() {
        //$scope.user.url = parenturl;
        console.log($scope.user._id);

        $http.user('/api/users', $scope.user).success(function(response){
            refreshuser();
            //$scope.user = {url: parenturl}
        });

    };


    $scope.remove = function(id) {
        console.log(id);
        $http.delete('/api/users/' + id).success(function(response) {
            //refreshuser();
        });

        return false;
    };

    $scope.edit = function(id){
        console.log(id);
        $http.get('/api/users/' + id).success(function(response) {
            $scope.user = response;
        });
    };

    $scope.update = function() {
        console.log($scope.user.id);
        $http.put('/api/users/' + $scope.user._id, $scope.post).success(function(response) {
            refreshUser();
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing good. Far better than what I was when I started thats for sure. I am not sure what the question is here but if you are looking for additional resources on your MEAN path, first I recommend using a [framework](http://hapijs.com/) it will cut down some dev time. There are many other alternatives.

I have also [read this book](https://leanpub.com/mean-machine) and I found it short and sweet and to the point. Book starts from zero and ends up with deploying an app live on [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/platform). Writers of the book also manage a site called [scotch.io](https://scotch.io/) and you will find some good tutorials on anything MEAN stack there.

If you want to learn more javascript in general there is also [egghead.io](https://egghead.io/). They have both free and paid tutorials there. Even the free ones are good sometimes.

If you want to learn more about mongo, definitely take classes from [mongo university](https://university.mongodb.com/) They are free and they are great. I have taken 4 classes so far and you get a certification of completion if you pass the class. Having the certs was definitely motivating for me and that may be motivating for you as well.

If you want to learn more about angular itself, I strongly recommend [Dan Wahlin's](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin) courses on udemy. I have taken two from him and they have literally shined a light and made angular make more sense to me.  If you do not want to pay the full price, I recommend waiting couple of weeks till thanksgiving in USA. Lots of online deals happen around those time. I took the courses for $10 each or something like that during a deal.

I have been a PHP developer for 6+ years. Thanks for nodejs at this point I am quite certain that the JavaScript is the future. Thats my personal opinion and I mentioned it ONLY hoping that it will give you courage and definitely not to start a discussion war. I hope I helped.

Comment: Hello ODelibalta, thank you very much for the information. I am actually taking an angular course by Dan Wahlin, as well as a nodejs course by Anthony Alicea.

Allow me to clear up the question. I am having trouble mainly with the relationships within the database. I understand how I can set it up, however, I am having issues when posting to the database, like say, create a post which belongs to a certain user, and belongs to a specific group. My main problem is that I do not know what that code looks like, and I am having trouble finding full examples that show code that does this. 

Thanks,

Comment: I have revamped my question, making it clearer. It can be found [here:] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789845/database-relationships-with-mongodb-how-to-post-to-database-using-angularjs)